# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el contenido de una variable obtenida de un SELECT a un TAG <a href = $_POST['var']?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, select

Quiero pasar el contenido de una variable obtenida de un `Select option` guardado en un campo de *MySQL* a una etiqueta `<a hrer = "">`. Ese valor que quiero pasar es una ruta.

¿Se puede hacer sin cambiar de página?

Copio el código que tengo:

```
<?php
   require "php/conexion.php";
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM templates';
   $result = $con->query($query);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEMPLATES</html>
</head>
<body>

<form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <select id="label" name="template" width="540" style="width: 540px">
        <option selected value="">Selecciona un TEMPLATE DISPONIBLE</option>
        <?php
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
            {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['location'];?>">
                <?php echo $row['template_name'];?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p style = "font-size:14px"><a class='iframe' href="<?php echo $row['location'];?>">SHOW TEMPLATE</a></p>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mediante Jquery. Obtienes el evento `change` de tu selector. A tu etiqueta `<a>` debes agregarle un `id`, supongamos `<a id="link" class='iframe' href="">`

```
$('#label').on('change', function() {
    //aqui obtienes el valor seleccionado de tu select
    var valor_seleccionado =  this.value;
    $("#link").attr("href", valor_seleccionado);
})
```

```js
$('#label').on('change', function() {
    var valor_seleccionado = this.value;
    $("#link").attr("href", valor_seleccionado);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="label">
  <option value="www.uno.cl">Uno</option>
  <option value="www.dos.cl">Dos</option>
  <option value="www.tres.cl">Tres</option>
</select>
<a id="link" href="www.google.com">Google COM</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con eso quedo resuelto